# How to hide the black line of the collapsed lines in Notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++

How do you remove a black horizontal line that always appears after you fold a block?

I have followed one of tips that said to use

> Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Default Style > Colour Style > Foreground Color: White`

but it made the filenames in Doc Switcher white too.

How do I make the black lines of folding disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/24314/hide-fold-lines/7),

1. Install NppExec through Plugin Manager.
2. Open the script window with Plugins > NppExec > Execute NppExec Script.
3. Add the following lines:

```
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETFOLDFLAGS SC_FOLDFLAG_NONE
sci_sendmsg SCI_GETELEMENTCOLOUR SC_ELEMENT_HIDDEN_LINE
set local $(NewColor) ~ $(MSG_RESULT) & 0x00FFFFFF
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETELEMENTCOLOUR SC_ELEMENT_HIDDEN_LINE $(NewColor)
```

4. Press the Save button and name the script.
5. Go to Plugins > NppExec > Advanced Options.
6. On the upper-right, choose the named script to be executed on Notepad startup.

For console to be hidden at Notepad startup, add `NPP_CONSOLE 0` as the top line of the script.

A different [solution](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/12265/disable-folded-function-underlining) doesn't work as of April 2022 because the LuaScript add-on doesn't work with Notepad++ 8.3.3.

Another [solution](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16484/how-can-i-hide-the-horizontal-lines-that-appear-when-i-fold-a-block) stopped working due to changes mentioned in the [thread](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/24314/hide-fold-lines/7).

Comment: Pretty cool. Never knew, that you could do this.